Flutter app showing white screen after first run in android emulator
I just made a new flutter project and run the defalut app that comes with it. First run went smoothly but every run after that showed a white screen after the splash screen. Seeing that terminal still displayed messages when I click where the "increase the counter" button is supposed to be, the UI still worked just wasn't displayed.
Cleaning the build did nothing, doctor said everything is good and there were no errors when running the app. Only way to show the UI again was to uninstall the app from the emulator and run flutter again, but after the first run the app still goes white no matter if I restart the run or exit the app and close it. It would be nice not have to do that every time I want to run the app but my main concern is that it will stay that way when I finish with development and build the app. Any help is much appreciated
UPDATE:
I'm starting to get scared. When I entered the app after closing it I got this on my screen and I'm not sure what kind of demons am I conjuring

Are you running the debug build? if yes, that may take lot of time to load the ui.
Please try running the app using flutter run --release and you'll be able to the expected behaviour is obtained

@albert yes I do run in debug. First time I run 'flutter run --release' it shows the UI but again, next time it is still white screen. Thanks for the info though.

Try to follow steps - flutter clean, in android folder run ./gradlew clean and flutter run.

@DroidFlutter as I said, I tried cleaning the build ( /build) but it unfortunatelly did nothing. Thanks for your time anyway :)

have you configured signatures for release build?

This issue usually happens with the android emulator and the same build works fine on a physical device.
Try to run following commands to clean and rebuild the project (it might help):
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter build


OK, I built the app and tried it on my IRL phone and it works fine, but when I try it in the emulator there is still a white screen so I guess it is an issue with the emulator. I'm glad the app isn't broken but it is still a pain to have to uninstall the app every time I close it in the emulator. You have any ideas how to fix that?

As you can see from the top banner on the screen, its a debug build.
Please run your app in release mode using flutter run --release
The build settings should be updated in build.gradle files.
refer to https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android , from signing the app.

I appreciate the help but I still do need it in debug mode because I am in the early stages of development. As for the release version I tried it and it doesn't work in the emulator but it's fine on the physical device.
